# Is there a way for np.save to work on MPI file objects?

Tags: python, numpy, mpi4py

I am running some "embarrassingly parallel" Python code on a cluster and want to save numpy arrays to .npy files in a way that each file will represent a data point (1-D array) that is regularly updated (i.e. becomes more statistically relevant); the idea is to minimize post-processing efforts. I am trying to use MPI to access random files within a set of possible files, potentially at the same time.

The method I am trying to use is `MPI.File.Open(comm, filename, amode, info, fh)` from `mpi4py`.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

def main():
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    size = comm.Get_size()
    rank = comm.Get_rank()
    fh = MPI.File.Open(comm, 'outfile.txt', MPI.MODE_RDWR|MPI.MODE_CREATE|MPI.MODE_UNIQUE_OPEN)
    if rank == 0:
      print(dir(fh))
      np.save(fh,np.random.rand(1))
    fh.Close()
```

The [documentation](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node175.htm#Node175) says that individual processes may open a file independently with MPI.COMM_SELF as the intracommunicator. When I try this in conjunction with np.save, I get a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/nas/longleaf/apps/python/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/compat/py3k.py", line 229, in os_fspath
    path_repr = path_type.__fspath__(path)
AttributeError: type object 'mpi4py.MPI.File' has no attribute '__fspath__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpleMPItest.py", line 112, in <module>
    main()
  File "simpleMPItest.py", line 35, in main
    np.save(fh,np.random.rand(1))
  File "/nas/longleaf/apps/python/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 514, in save
    file = os_fspath(file)
  File "/nas/longleaf/apps/python/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/compat/py3k.py", line 237, in os_fspath
    "not " + path_type.__name__)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not File
```

Going through the traceback:

```py
  File "/nas/longleaf/apps/python/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 514, in save
    file = os_fspath(file)
```

we get this block:

```py
    own_fid = False
    if hasattr(file, 'read'):  
        fid = file
    else:
        file = os_fspath(file) #line 514
        if not file.endswith('.npy'):
            file = file + '.npy'
        fid = open(file, "wb")
        own_fid = True

    if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
        pickle_kwargs = dict(fix_imports=fix_imports)
    else:
        # Nothing to do on Python 2
        pickle_kwargs = None

    try:
        arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
        format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
                           pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
    finally:
        if own_fid:
            fid.close()
```

The issue is that when I pass the MPI File to np.save, the MPI file object does not have a 'read' attribute, `npyio.py` tries to change that because it assumes it's not a file object, resulting in the TypeError.

Printing the MPI File Attributes:

```
['Call_errhandler', 'Close', 'Delete', 'Get_amode', 'Get_atomicity', 'Get_byte_offset', 'Get_errhandler', 'Get_group', 'Get_info', 'Get_position', 'Get_position_shared', 'Get_size', 'Get_type_extent', 'Get_view', 'Iread', 'Iread_all', 'Iread_at', 'Iread_at_all', 'Iread_shared', 'Iwrite', 'Iwrite_all', 'Iwrite_at', 'Iwrite_at_all', 'Iwrite_shared',
'Open', 'Preallocate', 'Read', 'Read_all', 'Read_all_begin', 'Read_all_end', 'Read_at', 
'Read_at_all', 'Read_at_all_begin', 'Read_at_all_end', 'Read_ordered', 'Read_ordered_begin', 'Read_ordered_end', 'Read_shared', 'Seek', 'Seek_shared', 'Set_atomicity', 'Set_errhandler', 'Set_info', 'Set_size', 'Set_view', 'Sync', 
'Write', 'Write_all', 'Write_all_begin', 'Write_all_end', 'Write_at', 'Write_at_all', 'Write_at_all_begin', 'Write_at_all_end', 'Write_ordered', 'Write_ordered_begin', 'Write_ordered_end', 'Write_shared', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'amode', 'atomicity', 'f2py', 'group', 'info', 'py2f', 'size']
```

shows that MPI files have 'Read' and 'Write' attributes instead. This raises another issue for when I get to this block:

```py
    try:
        arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
        format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
                           pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
```

because `format.write_array()` takes in a file_like_object with a `.write()` method.

Can I give an MPI file object `.read()` and `.write()` methods? I don't think I can make any changes to `npyio.py` because it's a university cluster.

Comment: Not sure what the relevance of “random files” is, but can’t you wrap the file object?  Note that `Read` is like `readinto`, not `Read`.

Comment: Just an overview of my general goal.